# @Transactional doesn't work with @Async in Websphere

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, websphere

I am trying to use `@Transactional` inside `@Async` method to track file conversion process as follows:

```
@Async
@Transactional
public void convertFile(String documentId) {
     
    CustomLog customLog = new CustomLog();
    customLog.setStatus("IN_PROGRESS");
    mySpringDataRepo.save(customLog);

    try {
      doConvertFunction(documentId);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
      customLog.setStatus("FAIL");
      mySpringDataRepo.save(customLog);
      return;
    }

    customLog.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    mySpringDataRepo.save(customLog);   
}
```

I am using the following technologies :

- **Spring Boot 2.7.18**
- **Hibernate Core 5.6.15.Final**
- **Websphere ND 9.0.5.13**
- **Java 1.8**

My custom EntityManager configuration:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    DataSource dataSource) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.myapp").persistenceUnit("MyEntityManagerFactory").properties(jpaProperties()).build();
    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    return em;
}

protected Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        return props;
}
```

When running the above code on Tomcat 9 It works perfectly fine, but when trying to run it on Websphere the transaction doesn't open and the save method doesn't get executed at all !

I made several tries with no luck as follows:

1. Using `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`
2. Extracting the save method to a new separate service method which is as follows:

   ```
   @Service
   public class MyService {

     @Autowired
     private MySpringDataRepo mySpringDataRepo;

     @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
     public CustomLog save(CustomLog customLog) {
        mySpringDataRepo.save(customLog);
        return customLog;
     }

   }
   ```

**UPDATE**:

The **only solution** worked on Websphere was by creating EntityManager from EntityManagerFactory as follows:

```
@Service
public class CustomLogService {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    
    public Long save(CustomLog customLog) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.persist(customLog);
        entityManager.flush();
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return customLog.getId();
    }

    public CustomLog find(Long id) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        CustomLog customLog = entityManager.find(CustomLog.class, id);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
        return customLog;
    }

    public void update(CustomLog customLog) {
        EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        entityManager.merge(customLog);
        entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

and changed my `@Async` code to be as follows:

```
@Async
public void convertFile(String documentId) {

    CustomLog customLog = new CustomLog();
    customLog.setStatus("IN_PROGRESS");
    customLogService.save(customLog);

    try {
       doConvertFunction(documentId);    
    } catch (Exception e) {
      customLog = customLogService.find(customLog.getId());
      customLog.setStatus("FAIL");
      customLogService.update(customLog);
      return;
    }

    customLog = customLogService.find(customLog.getId());
    customLog.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    customLogService.update(customLog);

}
```

I tried to inject entityManager as follows but it doesn't work only creating entityManager from EntityManagerFactory works:

```
@PersistenceContext(name = "MyEntityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

Are there any disadvantages/things to consider in this solution because I will be heavily using this method and it returns a new EntityManager instance each time it is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your configuration code to this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.myapp.dao" }, transactionManagerRef = "websphereTxManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebSphereDBConfiguration {

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/sample", name = "java:comp/env/jdbc/sample")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp.entity");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties());
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager websphereTxManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }


    protected Map<String, Object> jpaProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("hibernate.physical_naming_strategy", CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        props.put("hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy", SpringImplicitNamingStrategy.class.getName());
        return props;
    }


}
```

Use the same code :

```
@Async
@Transactional
public void convertFile(String documentId) {
     
    CustomLog customLog = new CustomLog();
    customLog.setStatus("IN_PROGRESS");
    mySpringDataRepo.save(customLog);
    
    try {
      doConvertFunction(documentId);    
    } catch(Exception e) {
      customLog.setStatus("FAIL");
      mySpringDataRepo.save(customLog);
      return;
    }

    customLog.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    mySpringDataRepo.save(customLog);
       
}
```

**Few points to be noted:**

1. Creating a bean of `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`.
2. Creating a bean of `EntityManagerFactory` via injecting `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and getting the object via `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.getObject()`. Also, make that bean as the primary bean for the whole application.
3. You will need to create a custom transaction manager. So, creating a `JpaTransactionManager` bean via injection and using the `EntityManagerFactory` bean.
4. You can see this annotation `@EnableTransactionManagement`. By use of this annotation, you will tell Spring to use this configuration class to manage your transaction.
5. See this annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories`. By this annotation, you will tell Spring which packages to scan containing the **JPA** repositories and also tell which transaction manager to use via this property `transactionManagerRef` by default.
6. You have to configure datasource on the WebSphere (I guess you already did) and inject it via `@Resource` and set that datasource in the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` bean.

See if this helps.

Comment: I tried your solution and It worked fine, sorry for replying late but I will award the bounty soon, thank you very much for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'am not used to websphere nor to recent version of jakartaEE

Just some general considerations :

- @Async methods defer the process to another thread.
- Transaction propagation rely on a threadLocal context and so the current transaction / entityManager instance is probably not reachable from your @Async method thread.
- All of this is very probably dependent on provider implementation. Maybe you could have better result using Container Managed transaction Manager provided by the Websphere server itself.
- Generally speaking using both a jakartaEE server and Spring might lead to additional complexity as their scope often overlap (You can use either Spring or JakartaEE containers in many cases: JPA, DI, Security, etc and problems will emerge if you mix features from both)
- Regarding your workaround, instantiating an new EntityManager instance for each method is not necessarily shocking, particularly if the method is directly invoked through a dedicated http request (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22773758/2087640)